# Como relacionar usuarios de FirebaseAuth con base de datos Realtime

Tags: android, firebase

tengo una duda con Firebase, quiero saber como hago que datos guardados esten asociados al usuario que esta logueado, por ejemplo si Pedro que es el usuario que esta logueado agrega algo a la base de datos que esto este relacionado a el, por ejemplo, Pedro termina una fase del juego y este acumula puntos y estos puntos se le deben almacenar en la base de datos y hacer una suma y asi continuamente mientras el mismo juegue.

Ya he logrado el registro de usuarios con el Auth por email, logeo, deslogueo, etc, pero tengo esa duda, dejo mi codigo de login

MainActivity

```
btnempezar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            corre = eduserr.getText().toString().trim();
            contraseña = passs.getText().toString().trim();
            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(corre,contraseña).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        eduserr.getText().clear();
                        passs.getText().clear();
                        startActivity(new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Status.class)));
                        finish();

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No registrado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    public void Empezar(){
    eduserr = findViewById(R.id.eduser);
    passs = findViewById(R.id.edpass);
    try{
        if (eduserr.getText().toString().isEmpty() && passs.getText().toString().isEmpty() ){
            eduserr.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.camp));
            passs.setError(getResources().getString(R.string.camp));

        }else{

            Intent empezar = new Intent(this, Status.class);
            empezar.putExtra("user", eduserr.getText().toString());
            startActivity(empezar);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.user), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Status

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status);
    contador = findViewById(R.id.txtcountdown);

    //inicia el servicio
    startService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    logoutt = findViewById(R.id.logout);

    logoutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(Status.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });

}

private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //aqui obtienes los datos enviados por el servicio
        //obtienes el tiempo que lleva
        if (intent.getExtras() != null){
            if (intent.hasExtra("Tiempo")){
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Tiempo");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
            } if (intent.hasExtra("Fin")){
                //se recibe que se ha finalizado el contador
                String tiempo = intent.getStringExtra("Fin");
                contador.setText(tiempo);
                contador.setEnabled(true);
                //cierras el servicio ya que no es necesario mantenerlo, sera creado al pulsar el boton nuevamente
                stopService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(ServicioTimer.PAQUETE));
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast registrado");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(br);
    Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast desligado");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(Status.this, ServicioTimer.class));
    Log.i(TAG, "Termina el servicio");
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogo.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.sal));
    dialogo.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    dialogo.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.conf));
    dialogo.setCancelable(true);
    dialogo.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.sali), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(Status.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    });

    dialogo.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.canc), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.conti), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    dialogo.show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez que pasaste este paso `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword...` ya tienes un usuario creado y se genera una sesion a partir de dicho usuario.

Una vez este paso termina, ya podes acceder al ID unico de ese usuario (que siempre va a ser el mismo)

para guardar datos en la base de datos del usuario logeado en ese momento (Pedro) , solo guardas todos los datos bajo su ID

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para probar, dentro de tu onCreate()

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child("Usuarios").child(firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Nombre").setValue("Pedro");
```

De esta forma, cada vez que guardes un valor `firebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid()` , va a hacer referencia al usuario logueado en ese momento.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona de maravilla, lo había visto ya en otro post, creo que también fuiste tu quien lo respondió.